# Using memcached with Java and ScheduledFuture objects

Tags: java, memcached, out-of-memory

I've been playing around with caching objects (by first creating my own cache which turned out a stable implementation but very inefficient) and then trying my hand at using Memcached.

Although memcached works beautifully, I've ran into a problem.

How I'm using my objects is as follows:

- I read data from a database into an object, then store the object in memcached.
- Every couple of minutes I retrieve the object from memcached, retrieve any additional data from either the database or other objects in memcached, update the object with any new / relevant data, then store the object back into memcached.
- Objects that need to be viewed are pulled from memcached, packaged and sent onto a client-side application for display.

This works very well, except when the number of objects I'm creating-storing-updating-viewing in memcached becomes high. Java/Tomcat-jvm doesn't seem to be garbage-collecting "fast enough" on the objects I pulled out of memcached, and the vm runs out of memory.

I'm limited to 8GB of memory (and would preferably like to bring that down to 4 if I can - using memcached), so my question is, is there a solution in preventing the JVMs memory usage from expanding so fast (or tune the garbage collector)?

(PS I have considered using Guava cache from Google, but this limits my options in concurrency e.g. if I have to restart tomcat, and using both Guava and memcached seems like a duplication of sorts which I'd like to avoid of possible)

--
Hein.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The garbage collector can't be "too slow" and run out of memory. Before throwing an OutOfMemoryError, the garbage collector is guaranteed to run. Only if it cannot free enough memory will the error be thrown.

You should use a profiler to see whether you have memory leaks, or if you're just hanging on to too many objects.

Afterwards you may want to tune the GC to improve performance, see for example here: [GC tuning](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html)